# Declare variables and return value in one statement in javascript

Tags: javascript

In many functions I have noticed the following pattern: function declares variables, combines it to the result and returns result. It is shown in this very simple example:

```
function fn() {
    var a = 1,
        b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
fn(); // 3
```

or:

```
function fn() {
    var a, b;
    return a = 1,
           b = 2,
           a + b;
}
fn(); // 3
```

I would like to minimize this code and reduce it to the one statement. It could look like this:

```
function fn() {
    return a = 1,
           b = 2,
           a + b;
}
```

However this code declares variables `a`, `b` in global scope which is not acceptable. Is it possible to do this in javascript?

Comment: You can't, `var` is a statement, and assignment is an expression; you need both. But you can do this `function fn(a=1, b=2){return a + b}`

Comment: Why not just return 1+2 ? why put it into variables if you just do an operation and then never use the variables afterwards?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. The `return` only returns the last value, the result of `a + b`.

Comment: One (frowned upon) trick you can use to skip the `var` (and `let`) declarations in functions without them ending up in the global scope, is to add them as (unused) function arguments, e.g. `function fn(a,b) {return (a = 1) + (b = 1);`, though for this exact example it would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this works for you, which is not advisable because of using assignment alogn with the comma operator.

```
function fn(a, b) {             // declaration in local scope
    return a = 1, b = 2, a + b; // return value with comma operator
}
```

A newer approach takes default values and returns just the addition of both.

```
fn = (a = 1, b = 2) => a + b;
```

Comment: This looks good, although I'm not sure if assigning values to parameters is the best practice in javascript

Comment: I mean from the clean code point of view. Assigning new values to parameters is considered to be a bad practice also in other languages (such as Java).

Comment: It is a Bad Practice to use the parameters to assign variables. The function parameters should not be used as `auxiliary variables`.

Comment: @Victor, i think op knows this problem. i would neither use the parameters nor the comma operator to do some operation in a return statement of a body of a function.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do (declare using `var` and `return` in same statement) is not possible with JavaScript syntax.

The most concise you can get is your first option:

```
function fn() {
    var a = 1,
        b = 2;
    return a + b;
}
fn(); // 3
```