# Declare + return abbreviation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a simpler/shorter, one-line declare + return syntax in TypeScript?

**Example:**

```
function test() {
    const sub = createSub(() => {
        sub.unsubscribe(); // need to use the result here
    });
    return sub;
}
```

Is it possible to make such code shorter, without a separate `return` line?

**UPDATE**

If running the code is needed, here's simplified code for `createSub`:

```
function createSub(cb: () => void): {unsubscribe: () => void} {
    setTimeout(cb);
    return {
        unsubscribe() {
           // do nothing
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @TylerRoper Nope. The code works perfectly fine, with the callback being delayed.

Comment: What's `createSub()`?

Comment: @jcalz `createSub` is some random function. In my code it will trigger the callback at a later point.

Comment: @vitaly-t you can do an implicit return I think: `return createSub(() => sub.unsubscribe() );`

Comment: @Yeysides Where's `sub` coming from in your example?

Comment: Usually I like a [mcve] so I can run the code myself and make sure I'm suggesting something reasonable.  Without the implementation of `createSub()` I'm not sure how to proceed.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @vitaly-t sorry, I forgot to mention that `createSub` needs to return the result of it's callback function.

Comment: @jcalz Ok, I have added a simplified implementation.

Comment: There's nothing *good* I can do here, I think.  You can abuse optional parameters like `const testCheating = (sub: Sub = null!) => (sub = createSub(() => sub.unsubscribe()));` which lets you call `testCheating()`.  Or you can build something like a [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) to both create and return a value in a single line, like `const test = () => fix<Sub>(getSub => createSub(() => getSub().unsubscribe()));`, but that's hardly "simpler".  The two-line solution in your question feels better than both of those, so ‍♂️

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare variables and return value in one statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493016/declare-variables-and-return-value-in-one-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: A `no solution` is understandable, and the likely outcome here. Otherwise somebody would have given the solution by now. I just thought maybe there was something I didn't get right from the TypeScript syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript define and return a variable on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145476/javascript-define-and-return-a-variable-on-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

Returning a variable declaration, e.g. `sub = createSub(...)`, will return the value of `sub`. Combined with arrow functions, you could do...

```js
const test = () => sub=createSub(() => sub.unsubscribe());
```

```js
function createSub(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb);
    return {
        unsubscribe() {
          console.log("unsubscribe");
        }
    };
}

const test = () => sub=createSub(() => sub.unsubscribe());

test();
```